# Liferay portal jquery not working after sometimes

Tags: liferay, liferay-7.3

I made a table with style and added jquery code in Liferay 7.3.1 GA2 and it works fine.

However, when I add a value to the table like one more to, the style is gone and jquery is not working anymore. But, if changed the whole HTML code, it works fine.

Is there any reason for this?

Comment: no no no no , this is not the way to post a question... Try again

Comment: There most likely _is_ a reason for this, but if we only know that you do _something_, we can only propose that you'll need to do _something else_. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and edit your question with additional information

Comment: @Mahmoud  when im correct,, query has been  removed in 7.3 GA 4 ..just if anybody tries this in later versions

Answer (score 0):

Check browser console for errors after changing the table. Most likely you'll find the reason there. Looks like jquery failed to load.